# Syntax Error in For Loop in Ubuntu Terminal vi editor

Tags: shell, syntax-error

```
for (( i=0; i<=5; i++ ))
do
        echo "$i Echoed"
done
```

this is what wrote in "bubble.sh" with vi editor and it gave me this error

> bubble.sh: 1: bubble.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

i don't seem to understand why this is happening..please help

Answer (score 1):

That style of `for` loop is a `bash` extension, not supported in the POSIX shell. You'll get that error if you run your script with an `sh` that isn't a link to `bash`.

Comment: i did add "#!/bin/bash" in the beginning of the script now it gives me an error saying "bubble.sh: 2: bubble.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable"